# Minecraft villagers won't stop spinning around in circles?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have version 1.8.1, and my villagers won't stop spinning around in circles. They won't go inside at night and get killed by mobs, and the farmers don't stop to replant crops. How do I stop them from spinning around?

Comment: Try destroying the block(s) they're standing on.

Comment: They seem to be stuck. You can try teleporting all of them up by one block with `/tp @e[type=Villager] ~ ~1 ~`, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Some things you can try:

1. Hit them with your fist
2. Break the block underneath them
3. Remove the doors on the building on then replace them.

Comment: Are you able to trade with them while they are spinning?